# Creating directory using Laravel 5 issue

Tags: laravel

This is my code:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\File;
.....
$path = public_path().'/uploads/users/'.Auth::User()->id.'/avatar/';
File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);
```

But the `uploads/users/2/avatar/` is not created. Any idea why ?

Comment: if you remove the last true on `File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true, true);` you will get some info!

Comment: I removed it , if i do a `var_dump(File::makeDirectory($path, $mode = 0777, true))` it returns me `false`

Comment: Do you get any error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you should change your code to

```
$result = File::makeDirectory($path, 0777, true);
```

Because `$mode = 0777` will evaluate to `true` and not to `0777`

Comment: I get this now : `mkdir(): Permission denied`

Comment: Well that **is** more clear: you lack rights as the user that runs the current code. You might want to `chmod` that first

Comment: so what exactly should I chmod it ? :D

Comment: Do you know how to find out what user is running your laravel project under and what right it has on the folders that exist (uploads/users/2/ ?) you may even be better of to test this code first in a custom artisan command! http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/62706/securely-running-lamp-under-a-specific-user might help you :)

Comment: my project runs on this user: `myuser`and on this group: `myuser`

Comment: and has myuser rights on the directory to create subdirectories AND chmod himself? I believe not so. Try running as root (as an experiment)

Comment: I just run `mkdir test` in my project root and it didn;t say permission. I manage to create a folder using the `Storage::makeDirectory` not `File::makeDirectory` and it created the folder with this user `daemon`. I'm not sure whats the diff. between them and when should I use them.

Comment: Is there a way to set in laravel, to create all files (upload files, logs) with a specific user and user group ?

Comment: I don't know for sure, but I would say only with raw OS commands